# What's the difference between random number evaluation among AIS-31 AIS-20 and NIST sp800-22

Tags: random, smartcard

I'm trying to know about the evaluation of random number generated by smart card chip. But these standards AIS-31, AIS-20 and NIST sp800-22 confuse me. Could someone help me with a brief explanation about them.

Thanks!